# About the files named identically in different directories in environmental variable 'PATH'

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I installed both 'Python 3.7' and 'Anaconda', with adding the installation directories into environmental variable 'PATH'. And now when calling 'python' in windows' cmd, it turned out to be the 'Anaconda' one. Is there any possibility to call another one directly in cmd?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: On Windows you can use the [`py.exe` launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?#python-launcher-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Try launching it through `C:\Python37\python.exe` from cmd. Basically the path is the installation folder of Python 3.7.